# get the start and end date of the droppable element in arshaw calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the example of arshaw full calendar droppable (http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-2.0.2/demos/external-dragging.html)
I want once is drop the element into the calendar to populate 2 fields with the start date and the end date.

```
<input type="text" id="StartDate" />
<input type="text" id="EndDate" />
```

Unfortunately the section of droppable in the website (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/dropping/droppable/) doesnt show how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

import your js and css files, you can see in the source page the codes

```
$('#my-draggable').draggable({
    revert: true,      // immediately snap back to original position
    revertDuration: 0  //
});

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    droppable: true,
minDate:yourDate,
maxDate:yourMaxDate,
    drop: function(moment, allDay) {
        alert("Dropped on " + moment.format() + " with allDay=" + allDay);
    }
});

<div id='external-events'>
            <h4>Draggable Events</h4>
            <div class='external-event'>My Event 1</div>
            <div class='external-event'>My Event 2</div>
            <div class='external-event'>My Event 3</div>
            <div class='external-event'>My Event 4</div>
            <div class='external-event'>My Event 5</div>
            <p>
                <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
                <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: I think you miss understood my question, what I ask is once is drop how can i get the start and end date, I didnt ask how to create a droppable!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution: I have add/modify the drop function (the one that is downloaded from the website).
they store the date when they do: copiedEventObject.start = date;

```
//GET THE START DATE AND MAKE IT IN MILISECONDS
var startDateMiliSeconds = Date.parse(date);
//MY MEETING WILL BE 1HOUR LONG
var endDateMiliSeconds = startDateMiliSeconds + 3600000;
// MAKE BOTH DATES DATE FORMAT
var Startdate = new Date(startDateMiliSeconds);
var EndDate = new Date(endDateMiliSeconds);
//THIS IS TO POPULATE THE INPUTS
$('#StartTime').val(Startdate);
$('#EndTime').val(EndDate);
```

The whole code is below:

drop: function(date) { // this function is called when something is dropped

```
// retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

// we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

// assign it the date that was reported
copiedEventObject.start = date;
var startDateMiliSeconds = Date.parse(date);
var endDateMiliSeconds = startDateMiliSeconds + 3600000;

var Startdate = new Date(startDateMiliSeconds);
var EndDate = new Date(endDateMiliSeconds);

//Startdate.toString("dd-mm-YYYY");
//EndDate.toString("dd-mm-YYYY");               

// render the event on the calendar
// the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

$(this).remove();
$('#StartTime').val(Startdate);
$('#EndTime').val(EndDate);
var edgarFabian = $.type(date); //date is an object
//alert(edgarFabian);
alert(Date.parse(date) );
}
```